# What kind of sorting does Kotlin use by default?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, kotlin

Which sorting is using for *.sort(), .sortWith()* etc methods?

```
val array = arrayOf(3,2,1)
```

Are there some differences in algorithms for arrays of different types and sizes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to extend on what [Marko Toplnik said in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964383/what-kind-of-sorting-does-kotlin-use-by-default#comment92836746_52964383): Be careful how you create your arrays, because based on that, different `sort` functions will be used.

---

```
val array = arrayOf(3,2,1)
array.sort()
```

which (in Kotlin/JVM) leads to:

```
public fun <T> Array<out T>.sort(): Unit {
    if (size > 1) java.util.Arrays.sort(this)
}
```

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/04bbf2393684fb7f552da667e8f28dfc1f83bbfb/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/generated/_ArraysJvm.kt#L1789-L1798

This will result in [`java.util.ComparableTimSort`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/ComparableTimSort.java) being used (see the [`sort(Object[] a)`](https://devdocs.io/openjdk~8/java/util/arrays#sort-java.lang.Object:A-))

---

```
val array = intArrayOf(3,2,1)
array.sort()
```

which (in Kotlin/JVM) leads to:

```
public actual fun IntArray.sort(): Unit {
    if (size > 1) java.util.Arrays.sort(this)
}
```

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/04bbf2393684fb7f552da667e8f28dfc1f83bbfb/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/generated/_ArraysJvm.kt#L1729-L1734

This will result in [`java.util.DualPivotQuicksort`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java) being used (see the [`sort(int[] a)`](https://devdocs.io/openjdk~8/java/util/arrays#sort-int:A-))

Comment: Could you please provide source where it is written Kotlin uses JDK sorting? Or point me to a file where I could find implementation of such usage? Thanks!

Comment: @Majkeee I added links to the answer

Comment: Good answer, but the source code is no guarantee it won't change to a completelly different algorithm in the next minor release, is it? Typically, API providers won't document what algorithm they use internally (implementation detail) but they might instead document the time complexity of their method. And the time complexity can often be a hint to the probable algorithm used.

Comment: Yes @DodgyCodeException this is exactly the case. This answers contains of two things: 1. CURRENT implementations for sorting `arrays` in Kotlin/JVM; 2. A general suggestion to watch out for details when creating an `array`, because this may affect the way you interact with it later on.
Looking at implementations at a particular time can be as simple as cmd+clicking (or ctrl+clicking) a method, but broadening the perspective of writing code is a whole different story.